# Making a plain ASCII/UTF-8 request/stream HTTP POST request in Python?

Tags: python, http

I'm reading some documentation on a service I'm trying to use, and it reads something like this:

> All requests must be sent using HTTP Post.
>
> The XML engine only accepts plain ASCII (text) UTF-8 requests/streams.  Encoded streams are not acceptable.

All requests/responses are XML.

But I really just don't understand what it's asking for.  From what I've been reading on [HTTP POST in Python](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml), you still need to encode key=value pairs to make a request, where it sounds like they just want the plain XML itself (as a multipart, maybe?  I am very confused).  Are they giving me enough information and I'm just fundamentally misunderstanding their documentation, or should I ask for more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [urllib2.Request](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request)

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request("http://foo.com/post_here", "<xml data to post>")
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

"plain ASCII UTF-8" is a contradiction in terms, IMHO -- ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, though. Try sending UTF-8 including some "special" (non-ASCII) character and see what happens (or, if you can, do ask them to reword said contradition-in-terms!-).

Comment: I think they're just missing an "or".  I don't think you understand my confusion - I don't know how to send either an ASCII or UTF-8 request, only how to send key=value requests...  just confused in general.

Comment: @Roger: Even "or" doesn't fit: One could just say "UTF-8" and that would mean ASCII is allowed as well since UTF-8 includes ASCII.